# using sql commands to look for records - tree structure in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I have this table with the names and birth/death dates of all my ancestors that I'm using for a genealogy website. The key is the ID and all the children's ParentID items will be set to the same as the parent's ID.

```
ID - int (key)
FirstName - string
Lastname - string
Born - int
Died - int
ParentID - int
hasChildren - bool
```

I want to show it in some type of tree structure (that's another problem for later) - for now I'm just showing them in a GridView. I have a button at the beginning of each row called Branch. When you click Branch on someone's record it calls a select function to retrieve the ID of the selected record so I can make a SELECT command to search all records with a ParentID that match that ID of the selected record. In doing so I will repopulate the grid with all children of the selected record (the parent). Since I don't want to show the ID and ParentID in the grid, I can't retrieve it using:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];
```

what I had in mind was something like:

```
        SqlDataSource ds = (SqlDataSource)GridView1.DataSourceObject;
    string selectstring = "SELECT [ID],[FirstName],[MiddleName],[LastName],[BirthDate],[DeathDate],[ParentID],[hasChild] FROM [test2].[dbo].[Geneology] where ParentID = " + x;
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = selectstring;
```

where x is the string of the selected records ID. I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the ID of the selected record without showing it in the gridview. I selected all columns when i made the datasource but made the ID and ParentID hidden. Now they aren't included in the rows of the gridview. Any ideas on how to go about this? I hope this explains it well enough.

[edit] OK - I fixed it. I had to set the DataKey to be ID so the GridView.SelectedValue returns the ID. Its working now. I just need to figure out how to go back one level without repopulating the grid with all records.

Comment: Do a google search for Joe Celko and you'll come up with some great articles and [examples](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something called Hierarchical Queries.

In Oracle you would do something similar to:

```
select t.*
from table t
connect by t.id = t.parent_id
start with t.id = my_id
```

Edit: Now that I read your question again, I think you're talking about some C# thingie, which I know nothing about, so nevermind my answer